# Notifier calling earlier then expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have following issue

```
0) Homepage having two button, Button A , Button B
1) TabbarviewC.h/TabbarviewC.m  //set in storyboard class its a subclass of UITabBarController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[self loadAPI];   
}

    -(void)loadAPI
    {

     //load my api
     //on success load another api and insert data in sqlite database
     //on completion of insert database i add notifier 

    [self databaseinsertComplete];
    }

-(void)databaseinsertComplete
{

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  postNotificationName:@"DataLoadedCompletely" object:nil];


}
```

2) I have load an API in TabbarviewC.m 
    3) I have 4 tabs (tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4) to be link with TabbarviewC

Now, according to situation , i need to pass data in all 4 tabs
also

```
If user Press button A -> it load the API and then jump to tab 1 

-(IBAction)ButtonA:(id)sender
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UITabBarController *tbc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
            tbc.selectedIndex=0;
            self.window.rootViewController = tbc;
            [UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:nil completion:nil];
}


If user press button B -> it will open the tab2

-(IBAction)ButtonB:(id)sender
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UITabBarController *tbc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
            tbc.selectedIndex=1;
            self.window.rootViewController = tbc;
            [UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:nil completion:nil];
}
```

In my tab1 or tab 2 i add the notifier addObserver to call a reload tableview function but its call to early before the data inserted in sqlite db

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadTableview)
                                                 name:@"DataLoadedCompletely" object:nil];
} 

-(void) reloadTableview
{
//my table view reload
//it loads the data from database and then reload the tableview
}
```

in both case i need to load the API data at TabbarviewC and on success of it i have to show the data in tab 1 , or tab 2

In my case, the API response get later and my tab shows empty tableview results at first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSNotificationCenter posts notifications synchronously. Not sure how you save data to your sqlite database but if you have a completion handler - you should use it to post a notification. Also, good thing here would be posting a notification asynchronously with [NSNotificationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/notificationqueue). Something like that:

```
NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"DataLoadedCompletely" 
                                                             object:nil];
[[NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue] enqueueNotification:notification
                                           postingStyle:NSPostASAP];
```

This way you will get your notification delivered right in time and you will have no race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, whatever you are doing to retrieve your data is running asynchronously... but you are sending the "complete" notification as soon as you *start* your data retrieval process.

```
-(void)loadAPI
{

 //load my api
 //on success load another api and insert data in sqlite database
 //on completion of insert database i add notifier 

[self goGetData]; // probably returns immediately

[self databaseinsertComplete]; // method is called *while* data is still being retrieved
}
```

So, if your "fetch data" process *is* async, make sure you are waiting for it to fully complete before you send your "DataLoadedCompletely" notification.

Comment: yes i did it the same +1 for those who get such problem.